# How can I block these external Youtube API JS scripts that are loading on my website through an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

To optimize my website load I've concatenated all my JS and CSS scripts into as few as possible. BUT, I'm still loading a couple extra through a Youtube embed iFrame that I'm using as a video background header. These 3 scripts are driving down my Google Page Speed Insight score (ironic considering the scripts are coming from youtube's servers).

How can I block these scripts from running, and then concatenate them into the rest of my scripts on the backend?

Comment: The scripts in the iframe *don't execute in the context of your page*. You don't want to 'copy them over' blindly, because then they will.

Comment: If  the biggest risk is running the code in the context of my code, then that's something I'm willing to try out. As it stands now, it's preventing me from getting a sufficient score on google page speed. It seems that google would surely have made some kind of work around for this right? There should be an option or something I could set with the embed code  maybe?